# android java change edittext direction when configuration changed

Tags: android, locale

I have an edittext in my android app which have 2 languages arabic and english, when update the configuration i need to change text direction to `right to left` when it is arabic language and `left to right` in english

i have added the below in manifest but it keep write from left to right in both languages

`android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale|screenSize"`

any solution to do it globally?

Comment: Have you checked or used `android:textDirection` ?

Comment: See this ---- https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html

Comment: @Piyush yes i tried it: it works only if the text is arabic, i need to write english data even if the app is in arabic